# replace whole collection with new with same name using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> Here i am trying to save collection with name **courseTitle** in
>   database using *monggose and nodejs* and if any collection exists with
>   the same name(*courseTitle*) while saving then it should replace the existing
>   collection. How can I replace the existing collection with new collection whenever i save, without using **remove()** and **save()**.
>
> **My approach**: first i deleted(remove()) the collection if exists and then saved(save()) again with same name.
>
> Is there any other technique of doing same?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var courseSchema = require('./video-course-events');

module.exports.saveEvent = function(req, res){  
var courseTitle = req.body.CourseDetails.courseTitle;

var Vcevents = mongoose.model(courseTitle, courseSchema);   
var vcevents = new Vcevents(req.body);

Vcevents.find(function (err, result){
    if(result.length) 
    {
        // replace the collection(eg, mycourse) with new using same name(ie, mycourse).
    }
    else if(err){
        console.log('Error occured..!!', err);
    }
    else{
        vcevents.save(function (err, results){
            if(err){
                res.json(err);
            }
            else{
                res.json(results);
            }
        });     
    }
});

}
```

Comment: Any reason you would want to wipe out the entire collection on a save? This just seems like a really bad idea to constantly be doing. Does the collection always only have one document in it?

Comment: yes, because i am running video using this collection which contains multiple events as an object. After saving multiple events(objects) first time in this collection i can go back and delete/add/modify any event(object) and it only get reflected in db when i click save button. First i am adding all events in an object and then throwing this object to save/update to db.

Comment: i am not making changes directly to the db. First all the modifications will be stored in an object which contains multiple events and then saving this object in db.

Answer (score 0):

You could use mongoose [findOneAndUpdate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) to achieve something similar without wiping out the collection. My mongoose is a little shaky but I think this would work.

```
Vcevents.findOneAndUpdate({}, vcevents.toObject(), {upsert: true}, function(err, doc){ //execute query });
```

Another potential option would be to use a [capped collection](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/). you could initialize the size of the collection one. This way every insert you make should get rid of the oldest document and replace it with the newest one. I've never personally used a capped collection but this is in theory how it should work according to the docs. I don't know if such a small limit would give it any problems.

```
db.createCollection("Vcevents", { capped : true, size : 5242880, max : 1 } )
```